# Is there anything (like iOS) that emulate force touch for older MacBook?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, trackpad

In iOS, there are tweaks (available through Cydia) that enables force touch features (such as menus) on older iPhones by touching and holding an item to emulate force touch.

Are there any available on OS X ?

If that matters, I own a late-2013 MacBook Pro

Comment: Is three-finger tapping not working for you? It doesn't directly emulate force touch, but it accomplishes most of its functions.

Answer (score 1):

If the sensor isn't there in the hardware, there is no way to enable the function.

It's the equivalent of trying to tun an old CRT television into a touch screen
[though that has actually been done, but not without some very expensive extra hardware]

Comment: No, iPhone 5S has no hardware 3D Touch, BUT using a tweak called Forcy, you can do what a strong touch does (quick actions) on an iPhone 6S by doing a long-hold touch on an old iPhone 5S.
Check out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UBRu0VLrO9o